# Is there a way to detect whether the Winform TextBox's Leave event was triggered by Tab or Shift-Tab or other event?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, customization

I will skip my code for now; it should be easier to describe in words.

So far I have the following logic working:

1. I have an input textbox, and when the user enters bad text, I show an error message and return the focus to the textbox.
2. When the user enters nothing or deletes what was there and leaves the textbox, it does some processing, but otherwise behaves as it would - jumps to the next control in Tab order.
3. If I Tab off, jumps to the previous control if I press Shift-Tab or focuses on whatever I click with the mouse.
4. If I enter a unique prefix for some text that can be auto-completed, such as "articho" that can be auto-completed to "artichoke", the code then auto-fills in another read-only textbox next to it and skips over to the next neighbor of the read-only textbox. **Note: If I Shift-Tab with the same input, then it does the same, but I would want to perform different logic in this case.**
5. Just like 4. but if I leave by clicking with the mouse, then the code does auto-fill in the textbox - great, but then it also selects the control that I want.

What is broken right now is **the bald part of 4.**; if I try to Shift-Tab to cycle all of the interactive (as opposed to labels or disabled ones) controls backwards, I cannot - my custom logic per 4. kicks in and sends the focus forward. This is only a problem when I have some stuff filled in in the textbox at hand, but I still would like to fix this edge case.

Any thoughts? Questions?

P.S. I do not know how to answer the "what have you tried?" type of question other than say that I was using WinForms for several months and I am not sure how to proceed here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might want to try PreviewKeyDown event of the textbox where you can identify Key combination that was being pressed and execute your different logic if it is Shift + Tab key press.

Comment: Thanks. As written I would not consider this as a complete answer. Since I still have a separate Leave event, then how do I get the two to communicate? Some sort of shared time that expires really fast, since the `KeyPreview` will occur right before the `Leave` event? To complicate things, I already intercept a `KeyPreview` event on the entire form, and do something on Page Up / Page Down. It should not take too long to exit out of that method when they key is neither Page Down / Page Up, but I am still not sure how to best pick the time interval. Also, any recommendations on Timer class usage

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LeaveTest {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            textBox2.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBox2_LostFocus);
        }

        void textBox2_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Control newControl = GetCurrentControl();
            Control prevControl = GetPrevControl(textBox2);
            Control nextControl = GetNextControl(textBox2);

            if (newControl.Handle == prevControl.Handle) {
                MessageBox.Show("Case 4");
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetNextDlgTabItem(IntPtr hDlg, IntPtr hCtl,
           bool bPrevious);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, GetWindow_Cmd uCmd);

        enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint {
            GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
            GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
            GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
            GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
            GW_OWNER = 4,
            GW_CHILD = 5,
            GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
        }


        private Control GetCurrentControl() {
            IntPtr hWnd = GetFocus();
            Control control = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
            return control;
        }

        private Control GetNextControl(Control ctrl) {
            // I know the last parameter looks wierd, but it works
            IntPtr hWnd = GetNextDlgTabItem(ctrl.Parent.Handle, ctrl.Handle, true);

            Control control = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
            return control;
        }

        private Control GetPrevControl(Control ctrl) {
            // I know the last parameter looks wierd, but it works
            IntPtr hWnd = GetNextDlgTabItem(ctrl.Parent.Handle, ctrl.Handle, false);
            Control control = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
            return control;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot. I am trying to minimize the reliance on the `user32.dll`, so if there are methods that technically do not need to go there, I would like to avoid making direct native calls. For instance, `getCurrentControl()` can be just `form.ActiveControl`; to get the next and the previous tab items, I could do `container.Controls` followed by a Linq query - more expensive, but works. So, I am curious - which functionality of the `user32.dll` do I absolutely need to achieve this? Thanks.